# Teamcenter (Siemens) Functionality with Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, teamcenter

I am currently working on a team which desires to extract data from Siemens' Teamcenter PLM software. We eventually want to make some dashboards in Tableau with the data, but want the data to automatically update as more data is populated into Teamcenter. Do Teamcenter and Tableau have this kind of functionality to work together?

Comment: As far I know, there is no such functionality. You may try to use Teamcenter Gateway for Enterprise Applications (T4EA), but it is not cheap. Otherwise it could be that Teamcenter EULA does not give permission to use data without licenses if you do some kind of customization. This is my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is by using Teamcenter Reporting and Analytics (eQ BI). If you have to use Tableau, then you will need to extract the data periodically (maybe into Excel) and run Tableau reports against that snapshot

Answer (score 0):

Colin is correct. You would have to write a simple query from Query Builder that gets data modified in a certain interval and configure it to run as a periodic job - basically building a utility out of it. So each time the utility is run, it passes the before and after times to the underlying Saved Query that will search for the modified data in Teamcenter. You can have this data converted to an XML format or a Json format and feed it to the APIs or input folder locations of Tableau. We followed this approach and even with our Tc modification rate being very high, this worked like a charm. In our case the reporting tool was HANA. Hope this helps you.